# Swift equatable conformance for large structs: Operator function '==' took xxx ms to type-check

Tags: swift

I have a large struct in Swift (often a must for SwiftUI), that I need to be `Equatable` (also to speed up SwiftUI) in multiple places of my app.

When I turn on the `-Xfrontend -warn-long-expression-type-checking=200` flag of the compiler, the equality operators get highlighted, some of them taking up to 0.5s (!) to type check.

Is there a way to rewrite the check to make the type check faster?

A sample of such check:

```swift
    public static func == (lhs: ScrollableGraphicForecastView, rhs: ScrollableGraphicForecastView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.viewId == rhs.viewId
            && lhs.nowHash == rhs.nowHash
            && lhs.canScrollAndFitAll == rhs.canScrollAndFitAll
            && lhs.forecast == rhs.forecast
            && lhs.renderContent == rhs.renderContent
            && lhs.renderContext == rhs.renderContext
            && lhs.renderOptions == rhs.renderOptions
            && lhs.renderData == rhs.renderData
            && lhs.daysOutlookSource == rhs.daysOutlookSource
            && lhs.dataSettable == rhs.dataSettable
            && lhs.colorScheme == rhs.colorScheme
            && lhs.fineHorizontalSizeClass == rhs.fineHorizontalSizeClass
            && lhs.aspectRatio == rhs.aspectRatio
            && lhs.scrollStep == rhs.scrollStep
            && lhs.scrollStepCount == rhs.scrollStepCount
            /// State
            && lhs.scaleInProgress == rhs.scaleInProgress
            && lhs.scaleAnchor == rhs.scaleAnchor
            && lhs.scale == rhs.scale
            && lhs.scaleCoefficient == rhs.scaleCoefficient
            && lhs.lastScaleValue == rhs.lastScaleValue
            && lhs.visibleChartStartRelative == rhs.visibleChartStartRelative
            && lhs.absoluteScrollOffset == rhs.absoluteScrollOffset
            && lhs.containerSize == rhs.containerSize
            && lhs.chartSize == rhs.chartSize
            && lhs.midScreenAbsoluteScrollOffset == rhs.midScreenAbsoluteScrollOffset
            && lhs.stagger == rhs.stagger
    }
```

The only relevant info I found is [this thread](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-equality-operator-takes-long-time-to-type-check/41226) - the gist of it is that there are many `==` operators to consider in each case, but I would say that for a struct or scalar type, this shouldn't be hard, and you can compare each pair of the comparison separately ...

Comment: You could do `guard lhs.viewId == rhs.viewId else { return false }; guard lhs.nowHash == rhs.nowHash else { return false} ... return true`. maybe to have quicker compiling?

Comment: You say this is a `struct`. [SE-0185](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md) saves us for having to write these sorts of mind-numbing methods for `struct` types. Are you sure you need this method at all?

Comment: @Rob In my case I have some non-equatable fields in some structs, or internal fields that shouldn't affect the equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that it's one massive expression, and that really is quite hard on the compiler. The syntax I would recommend is `if`:

```
if
    lhs.viewId == rhs.viewId,
    lhs.nowHash == rhs.nowHash,
    ...
    lhs.stagger == rhs.stagger
{
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

This breaks the work up into many small expressions, which are easier to type-check.

That said, I'd also reevaluate what's preventing you from using the built-in conformance. All visible properties should be part of Equatable anyway, and the built-in conformance will prevent future mistakes if you add properties, or cut-and-paste errors that can happen for properties with the same type.

Comment: Thank you, that still reads well, and doesn't create interdependencies between the comparisons. I'll see where I could use the built-in conformance, but in some cases I pass a closure to the component (to let it trigger some action without having a whole ViewModel as a dependence), but I want to exclude that closure from equality check (as it would always evaluate to false -> performance problems).